# How to pass dynamic amount to Paypal React SDK Button without re-render

Tags: reactjs, paypal

I'm using `react-paypal-js` and need to set a dynamic amount when the PayPal button is clicked.

The problem: the `createOrder` function can not take data from my state (might because it is under PayPal script context).

**Not Working Example:**

```
    const [amount, setAmount] = useState('');

    const handleCreatePaypal = (data, actions) => {
        const orderAmount = parseFloat(amount).toFixed(2) || '1.00'; //amount is the state
        console.log(amount, orderAmount)
        return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [
                { amount: { value: orderAmount } }
            ]
        })
    }

    return (
        <PayPalScriptProvider options={paypalOptions}>
            <PayPalButtons
                createOrder={(data, actions) => handleCreatePaypal(data, actions)}
                onApprove={(data, actions) => handlePaypalApprove(data, actions)}
                onError={handlePaymentError}
            />
        </PayPalScriptProvider>
    )
```

**Not Perfect Solutions:**

1. Get amount from **HTML**, but I don't really want to do that.

```
    const amountRef = useRef(null);  //ref on input not showing here
    ...
    const orderAmount = parseFloat(amountRef.current.value).toFixed(2) || '1.00'; //get value from html
    ...
```

2. **Force re-render** when amount changes. But this will result as the button disappear and show again whenever amount changes.

```
        <PayPalScriptProvider options={paypalOptions}>
            <PayPalButtons
                createOrder={(data, actions) => handleCreatePaypal(data, actions)}
                forceReRender={[amount]}  //force re-render when amount changes
            />
        </PayPalScriptProvider>
```

Any solutions to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

If there is no solutions, I might need to integrate from backend :(

I don't want this to be much complex since it is just a simple donate button.

Comment: I just whipped up a sandbox and it's pulling data from the state just fine. Are you sure you are correctly setting the state?  https://codesandbox.io/s/paypal-scratch-70yv7

Comment: @ShatteredDev Thanks for your time first. I just tested your code but the thing is you didn't change the state value (paypal button stored the initial value of the state). If you try to change the value with an `input`, you will find the problem.

Comment: @ShatteredDev I've added `<input value={amount} onChange={(e) => setAmount(e.target.value)} />` to your code, don't know if it updates on your side. You might notice the amount doesn't change when calling `createOrder`

Comment: Oh man, that's extremely annoying. As the buttons are rendered in an IFrame, there's no way of updating it without just completely destroying the IFrame. Maybe use a debounce so that it doesn't rerender and disappear with every keystroke?

Comment: @ShatteredDev Great Idea! But it is still not perfect. I would like to find a (#1 perfect, #2 simple) solution. Otherwise, I'll just integrate from backend. Thank you for pointing out the `iframe` that I didn't notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrating from a backend is the most robust solution in general, especially for ecommerce -- but as this is for a simple donation use case I can see how you may wish to avoid that.

There are various possible solutions, including using an additional state framework such as Redux, but it seems what you want to do is manage the state at a parent component level above the buttons, and `bind` its createOrder ("handleCreatePayPal") methods, etc so that `this` is in context and they can access *its* state.

[Here is a runnable codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/paypal-buttons-with-dynamic-amount-no-rerender-qd3rh?file=/src/App.tsx)  (based on the [documented example that uses a re-render](https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/example-paypalbuttons--dynamic-amount), but none is done here)

```
import { PayPalScriptProvider, PayPalButtons } from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";
import * as React from "react";

const debug = true;

const initialState = {
  amount: "2.00",
  orderID: "",
  onApproveMessage: "",
  onErrorMessage: ""
};

export default class App extends React.Component<{}, typeof initialState> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = initialState;

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.createOrder = this.createOrder.bind(this);
    this.onApprove = this.onApprove.bind(this);
    this.onError = this.onError.bind(this);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) {
    this.setState({
      amount: event.target.value,
      orderID: "",
      onApproveMessage: "",
      onErrorMessage: ""
    });
  }

  createOrder(data: Record<string, unknown>, actions: any) {
    if (debug) console.log("Creating order for amount", this.state.amount);
    return actions.order
      .create({
        purchase_units: [
          {
            amount: {
              value: this.state.amount
            }
          }
        ]
      })
      .then((orderID: any) => {
        this.setState({ orderID: orderID });
        return orderID;
      });
  }

  onApprove(data: any, actions: any) {
    let app = this;
    return actions.order.capture().then(function (details: any) {
      app.setState({
        onApproveMessage: `Transaction completed by ${details.payer.name.given_name}!`
      });
    });
  }

  onError(err: Record<string, unknown>) {
    this.setState({
      onErrorMessage: err.toString()
    });
  }

  onClick() {
    if (debug) console.log("When clicked, amount was", this.state.amount);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ minHeight: "300px" }}>
        <table className="table" style={{ maxWidth: "400px" }}>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>
                <label htmlFor="amount">Order Amount: </label>
              </th>
              <td>
                <select onChange={this.onChange} name="amount" id="amount">
                  <option value="2.00">$2.00</option>
                  <option value="4.00">$4.00</option>
                  <option value="6.00">$6.00</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Order ID:</th>
              <td>{this.state.orderID ? this.state.orderID : "unknown"}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>On Approve Message: </th>
              <td data-testid="message">{this.state.onApproveMessage}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>On Error Message: </th>
              <td data-testid="error">{this.state.onErrorMessage}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <PayPalScriptProvider options={{ "client-id": "test" }}>
          <PayPalButtons
            createOrder={this.createOrder}
            onApprove={this.onApprove}
            onError={this.onError}
            onClick={this.onClick}
          />
        </PayPalScriptProvider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just took a quick look of your example. Seem like what you did is change the functional component to a `class`, right? which solved the context issue. I'll take more time on reviewing it tomorrow. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: A class was necessary so all the methods could be bound (`bind`) to its context

Comment: I tried other methods like bind context to fucntion `handleCreatePaypal.bind(context)` -> failed, add an additional `ContextProvider` out of `PayPalScriptProvider` -> result in same re-rendering issue. I don't have any `class component` in my project and would not add one. But seems like it is the only solution simple to do for now. Thanks!

Comment: Functional components would probably require a useRef

Comment: Is it my #1 not perfect solution? Or is it possible to bind ref as context in functional component? I've wrapped only paypal button into a class component and will update to here for other people if there is no better solutions.